# Efficiently Forwarding a Response Body in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memory, asp.net-web-api2

I have a service (A) that retrieves JSON from another service (B) and sends it back to the client.

The `HttpContent.ReadAsAsync<object>()` API works fine, however it seems this needlessly requires more memory allocation. Afterall, we already have a representation of the JSON bytes via `HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()`.

What would be the most efficient way to forward the body from service B to the client, without needing to deserialize?

I am not using .NET Core, so the Response.Body stream isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

You should restream response from Service B to the client using Response.OutputStream